# Можно ли использовать "будние" без "дни" как существительное? Аналогично "выходным"

Tags: грамотная-речь

При написании статьи возник спор по поводу употребления слова "будние" как существительного.
Пример:

> Меня можно увидеть на кафедре в будние.

На мой взгляд можно сказать либо "в будни", либо в "будние дни". 
И нельзя использовать в качестве примера слово "выходные", так как у "выходных" нет формы "выходни" аналогичной будням.

Будет ли это ошибкой оставить текст, как в примере? Работает ли [субстантивация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) для слова "будние"?

EDIT:
Думаю можно в качестве аргументов буду использовать ответы ниже.

А в качестве "источников" использовать отсуствие использования слова будние без дней на нацкорпусе и просто толковые словари. Выходной - есть такое существительное в словарях, а будний - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы попытался разубедить автора, придумавшего антоним "выходным", равноценным просторечием:

> Меня можно увидеть на кафедре в рабочие.

Здесь столь же безосновательна попытка отбросить существительное (если оно не упоминалось прямо перед этим), которое не является единственно возможым в сочетании с прилагательным. Словари приводят и сочетание "будний вечер". И разумеется, такое "сокращение" неспособно конкурировать с обычным "будни" по количеству букв.

Единственный случай, когда такое употребление допустимо, не связан с субстантивированием: возможна отсылка прилагательного к *ранее названному* существительному:

> По выходным *дням* я всегда на даче, но меня можно увидеть на кафедре в
>   *будние*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую такой аргумент

Answer (score 1):

Много вопросов, но в общем-то на все есть один ответ. Форма "будние" сама по себе - разговорная, граничащая с просторечием и используется только в сочетании "будние дни".  Поэтому ""будние дни" - уже сомнительно, а просто "будние" - некорректно.

Ситуация здесь следующая. У слова "будни" нет единственного числа, форма "будень" считается устаревшей. В качестве замены в современном языке используется сочетание "будний день". Но при этом такое сочетание не употребляется (вернее сказать: до недавнего времени не употреблялось) во множественном. Оно не нужно, поскольку исходное "будни" охватывает всю сферу возможного употребления.

Кстати говоря, слово "будни" не совсем точный антоним для "выходные (дни)", антонимичная пара: будни - праздники.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Я с этим всем согласен, но я нигде не могу найти какого-либо источника или правила, который бы подтверждал это

Comment: Так вряд ли найдете. А какой может быть источник, ***подтверждающий***, что так нельзя? Нельзя ж на каждую ошибку (совсем не частую) писать отдельное правило или инструкцию?! Источник тут только отсутствие простых указаний, что так можно или хотя бы авторитетного примера. Так во всем нацкорпусе нет ни одного примера на "будние" без "дни". Думаю, в данном случае подобное можно считать "источником".